# Calculate ratio two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table1 has a "call" column and Table2 has a "pickup" column.

I want to find the call to pickup ratio but can't wrap my head around it.

I am using sqlite.
I have tried this

> SELECT (SELECT count (call)FROM table1)*100/ (SELECT count (pickup)  FROM table2)

but I get a number and not a decimal back

Comment: Multiply by `100.0` instead of `100` to avoid integer division.

Comment: @forpas thanks! now that i have that sorted i need to find out what was the ratio per week. any ideas on that?

Comment: Post sample data for both tables and expected results to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does integer division.  So, `1/2` is `0` rather than `0.5`.

So, the simplest method is to use `100.0` instead of `100`:

```
SELECT ((SELECT count(call) FROM table1) * 100.0 /
        (SELECT count(pickup) FROM table2)
       ) as call_to_pickup_ratio
```

This, in turn, runs the ricks of a divide by zero.  The solution for that is `NULLIF()`:

```
SELECT ((SELECT count(call) FROM table1) * 100.0 /
        (SELECT NULLIF(count(pickup), 0) FROM table2)
```

Finally, if `call` and `pickup` are never `NULL`, then you can just use `COUNT(*)`:

```
SELECT ((SELECT count(*) FROM table1) * 100.0 /
        (SELECT NULLIF(count(*), 0) FROM table2)
```